# What do I add to my requirements.txt in Django directory in order to push it to Heroku?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I am new to programming/web development and I want to push a Django directory to heroku. But every time I enter "git push heroku master" into my command line I get the same error:

```
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r /tmp/build_602f#############86ff270e/requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )"
```

I activated the virtual environment, but to no avail. Now I assume that the problem might be that my requirements.txt file does not contain anything (as I thought there would not be a reason for that, anyway). Still, I wonder what `"bonjour-py==0.3"` is and how that could be fixed. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can follow the answer from Kostas, or alternatively, if really only `bonjour-py` is missing, install it on heroku with `pip install bonjour-py`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that python2.7 and python3.x are different versions. You need the same version of python - server and local.

ToDos:

1. Take the terminal an go to the project directory

   cd /your/path/to/project/
2. Activate your virtualenv

   source env/bin/activate
3. Generate requirements.txt with pip

   pip freeze > requirements.txt
4. Go to your server and create new virtualenv with same python version (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#cmdoption-p)

   virtualenv --python=python2.7 env
5. Activate virtualenv on server

   source env/bin/activate
6. Install requirements.txt with pip

   pip install -r requirements.txt
7. Django migrations

   python manage.py migrate
8. Start django with runserver (to test) or connect webserver (nginx, uwsgi, gunicorn, ...)

   python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 12):

Inside your Python virtual environment and in your project path, just type:

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

This will list inside the `requirements.txt` file the exact version of each python package you use. And that's how Heroku will know what packages it needs to install in order to run your Django app.

Comment: Also make sure to use the same Python version as on heroku. At least don't mix Python 2 and 3. Many libs are unavailable for some Python versions.

Comment: I believe that I use the wrong version of Python now. I was using python-2.7.10 which I guess lead to a conflict. I updated python to python-3.6.2, but still, my terminal tells me that I use python-2.7.10. Creating an alias did not work, either. Any ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: in my case, this only works from the code editor terminal....not the BASH